# Setup SSL keys when using roles-profiles pattern with Puppet

Tags: ssl, configuration, puppet, deployment, provisioning

Here is a scenario. I have two web applications (lets call them webapp1 and webapp2) that needs apache, php (with some modules), and the web app's code it self. This is how I set this I set this up (using the roles-profiles pattern):

```
modules/
  apache/
  php/
  webapp1/ # responsible for cloning the repo and setting up config files
  webapp2/ # responsible for cloning the repo and setting up config files
  profiles/
    manifests/
      webapp1.pp # responsible for putting the stack together
      webapp2.pp # responsible for putting the stack together
```

profiles/manifests/webapp1.pp looks something like this:

```
class profiles::webapp1 {
  include ::apache
  include ::php
  include ::webapp1
}
```

and profiles/manifests/webapp1.pp looks something like this:

```
class profiles::webapp2 {
  include ::apache
  include ::php
  include ::webapp2
}
```

Now both the applications also have to be served over HTTPS and need the same set of SSL certificates (imagine webapp1 and webapp2 are served from different subdomains of a domain and we have a wildcard certificate so both the applications can use the same certificate). Now, I can't decide the manifest to do the SSL setup in (i.e. setting up keys and certs using `file` type. The reason is that at least right now, I am going to have both webapp1 and webapp2 in the same role manifest but would like to be flexible so that I can move webapp1 and webapp2 in different roles without worrying about doing SSL setup differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put them in a separate class, e.g. "wildcard_ssl_", and probably include that from both of 'webappX' classes, or maybe from both profiles instead.